# Consulta sobre nodejs y android ,usar api o consultas a la bd

Tags: android, nodejs, rest, mongodb

Quiero saber si para hacer una aplicación en android , ¿debería conectarme y hacer las consultas directamente a la bd , o usar una API? , actualmente he hecho una web en express/nodejs y mongo usando jade y angular para el manejo de plantillas y parte del front, en la cual cada endpoint me renderiza una pagina con los datos respectivos ,tengo los siguientes endpoint , solo pondré algunos.

```
GET /user/perfil/:id/eventos   --Lista de eventos suscritos o creados(tuyos)
GET /user/perfil/:id/eventos/:id  -`-Muestra el evento x o debería redirigir a /eventos/:id ??`
GET /user/perfil/:id   --Te muestra el perfil con id tal
GET /eventos             --Te muestra la lista de eventos creados(todos)
GET /eventos/:id        --Vuelve a mostrar el evento x (publico para todos)
```

He puesto solo los gets , y algunos ,con una pequeña duda en el 2° 5° endpoint, ahora bien si quiero consumir los datos desde android, estoy viendo crear un endpoint parecido a lo siguiente.

```
  GET  "/api/users"
  GET  "/api/eventos"
  GET "/api/rectififaciones"
```

Siendo que a la api , le tendría que poner un middleware para que solo sea accesible a través de un token , ¿tal vez jwt?, esta bien mi lógica o de que otra manera podría hacerlo, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo API, de esa manera solo puedes hacer uso de GET,POST y DELETE en tu aplicación. No es muy recomendable tener las bd dentro de tu app y mas si vas a manejar información delicada.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que eso pasa por decisión tuya, todas las ideas que diste son validas. Ahora,  en lo personal he trabajado con Android y WS hechos en `PHP` Y en `.NET` y en cuanto a seguridad, generaba *hash* para cada usuario con el cual verificaba si tenía o no autorización para dicha función. También te recomiendo y sería bueno trabajar con bases de datos `SQLite` para hacer funcionar tu `APP` de forma *offline* si lo deseas.

Answer (score 1):

Te puedo recomendar ampliamente revisar la tecnología [Amazon Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/es/lambda/details/) para que las Lambdas puedan realizar operaciones con tu base de datos y regresar resultados a Android. La forma de hacerlo es con un Post, para lo cual utilizo [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), es la forma más sencilla y segura que he encontrado de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

No te recomiendo llamar a tu base de datos directamente desde tu aplicación Android, eso implicaría que tu app tenga en su código las credenciales para la conexión a la base de datos, las cuales pueden ser extraídas de tu app usando ingeniería inversa, y concederá un acceso inmediato a tu base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo q lo mejor es usar REST como estas proponiendo. Ahora bien, a la hora de implementar la seguridad por token, creo que Oauth2 es tu mejor apuesta en estos momentos.